# Movement across cube

Tags: combinatorics

A particle is initially at vertex of cube. In each step it moves along the edge of cube from one vertex to another vertex.find number of ways in which it can reach opposite vertex in five or fewer steps. It stops after reaching opposite vertex.

My solution: i treated sides of cube as x ,y ,z . 
Case 1: three steps so arrangement of x ,y ,z that is 3! =6
Case 2: arrangement of x ,x ,-x ,y ,z which gave 14
Hence 14 *3 + 6 =48
Which is correct answer.

Can there be some other good method?

Comment: where is the 14 coming from? I don't quite see it.

Comment: "14" should be 20: ${5\choose 3}=10$ to pick the steps that use the back and fourth axis. Times $2$ to account for order of the steps for the other axes. Then the total is $66$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least three steps is needed. Not possible with four steps. So:

[image: Traversing a cube]

Answer (score 1):

We have to move along each of the three axex an odd number of time.

With three steps,we must take each axis eaxctly once, after permutation that's $3!$.

Four steps are not possible.

With five steps, exactly one axis is used three times. This give $3$ (pick the special axis) times $5$ (pick the step using one of the other axes) times $4$ (pick the step using the third axis), or $60$.

In total

$$ 60+6=66.$$

Comment: Your count of 5-step paths includes each 3-step path three times. These need to be excluded.

Comment: Yes, the 5-step paths that already reach the opposite vertex after 3 steps shouldn't be counted.